Mesh Looks pixelated with boolean modifier
I want to cut a shallow hole in this mesh but i'm struggling to stop the edges from looking pixelated, I tried subdividing a larger area and smoothing but it's still a mess. Any tips? Thank you :)


Maybe use a low-poly topology and you won't have any pixelation:

Modeling:

